# For $a>1$ and $x>y>0$, is it true that $(x-y)^a+y^a-x^a\leq 0$?

Tags: calculus

Let $a>1$ and $x>y>0$. How can we prove (if it is true) that $$
(x-y)^a+y^a-x^a\leq 0?
$$
Im not sure if this is true, I'd acutally like to use this to solve an excersise since I have the feeling that it is true (at least for $a\in\mathbb{N}$). However, since $a$ is real, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: One idea might be to divide everything by $y^a$, put $x/y=t$ and use basic calculus to check the inequality for whatever range of $t$ is appropriate.

Comment: With $d = x-y$ this is $d^a + y^a \le (d+y)^a$, which is proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/836337/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $(x+y)^a > x^a + y^a$ for $x,y>0$ and $a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836337/show-xya-xa-ya-for-x-y0-and-a1)

Answer (score 0):

Since $x>y$, let  $x=y+k$, then $(x-y)^a=(y+k-k)^a=k^a\leq(y+k)^a-y^a$, which is equivalent to $x^a+y^a\leq(x+y)^a$, which is of course true, if we expand $(x+y)^a$.

Comment: Note that $a$ is a real number, not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @MartinR, but we can do the binomial theorem even if $a$ is not necessarily an integer. Also, we can work with the power means inequality, there are so many ways to show that.